CKEditor with Outlook
Outlook does not support images sent through CKEditor, that is, if I give the image a size of, for example, 400px in CKEditor, the dimensions are displayed in an enlarged state in Outlook. I need to be able to give the size I want in CKEditor and have the same size displayed in outlook.
When I resize an image from CKEditor. The image should be visible in Outlook at the same size
